# Append multiple chars to string in C++

Tags: c++, string, append, concatenation

Using `+` is a valid way to append a char to a string in C++ like so:

```cpp
string s = "";
s += 'a';
```

However,

```cpp
string s = "";
s += 'a' + 'b';
```

gives a `warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value` and does not append `a` and `b` characters.

Why does the first example append the char and the second does not?

Comment: Because the latter works like `s = s + ('a'+'b')`. You're adding the two char together first before appending them.

Comment: hint: `'a'+'b'` is an integer 195. Try `s += "ab"`.

Comment: `char`s are an integer type with special display rules that allow you to see them as characters. Unfortunately, in this case, this means when you add two `char`s you don't append them, you sum the two numeric values of character's encoding.

Comment: Should be `(s +='a') +='b';`, isn't it?

Comment: No. think of `+=` as a function and you won't be far wrong. The parameters of the function are resolved before the call. Oh wait. Are you suggesting a code change, @康桓瑋 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with **operator precedence**. Let's take for example the expression:

```
string s = "";
s += '0' + '1';//here + has higher precedence than +=
```

Here `+` has higher precedence than `+=` so the characters `'0'` and `'1'` are group together as `('0' + '1')`. So the above is equivalent to writing:

```
s+=('0' + '1');
```

**Next**, there is **implicit conversion** from `char` to `int` of both `'0'` and `'1'`. So `'0'` becomes the decimal 48 while the character `'1'` becomes decimal 49.

So essentially the above reduces to:

```
s+=(48 + 49);
```

or

```
s+=(97);
```

Now 97 corresponds to the character `a` and therefore the final result that is appended to the string variable named `s` is the character `a`.

Now lets apply this to your example:

```
string s = "";
s += 'a' + 'b';
```

**First** due to precedence:

```
s+=('a' + 'b');
```

**Second** implicit conversion from `char` to `int` happens:

```
s+=(97 + 98);
```

So

```
s+=195;
```

So the character corresponding to decimal 195 will be appended to string s.

You can try out adding and subtracting different characters to confirm that this is happening.

> Why does the first example append the char and the second does not?

So the **fundamental reason** is operator precedence.

Comment: I'd upvote if you mention that the decimal equivalents are contingent on the near-ubiquitous but by no means required ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 1):

That's a drawback with operator overloading; one needs to remember it is little more than a syntactic sugar and a nice way of calling functions.

```
s += 'a' + 'b';
```

is grouped as it would be for a simple expression like

```
a += 1 + 2;
```

for an `int` type `a`.

In other words `'a' + 'b'` is evaluated first. And that has an `int` type due to argument promotion rules. A `std::string` has no specific overload for `+=` for an `int`, only one that is normally a narrowing conversion, so the compiler issues a warning.

If you want to append `"ab"` to the string `s`, then use

```
s += "ab";
```

Answer (score -1):

Change it to this:

```
s += 'a';
s += 'b';
```

In simple terms, the `std::string::operator+=()` does not work as you wish because in the statement `s += 'a' + 'b';`, the **priority/precedence** of the `+` is greater than the assignment `=` operator. This means that the compiler will first evaluate `'a' + 'b'` and will then evaluate the assignment `=`. Thus it will assume that it's an addition of two `char`s which usually is a 1-byte integer under the hood.

Adding the ASCII values of `a` and `b` will return **97+98 == 195** but the max value of `char` is 255. So this will cause an overflow and then wrap around and will eventually result in **195-256 == -61** and -61 is not part of ASCII so what you will see depends on your specific terminal.

`s += 'a' + 'b';` is like you're trying to add two ASCII values and then append the resulting `char` (which is terminal-specific) to `s`. And that's why you are not seeing your desired characters being printed.

When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::string str( "" );
    str += 'a' + 'b';
    std::cout << "The char is: " << str[ 0 ]
              << " and its ASCII value is: " << +str[ 0 ] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

in the Windows command prompt I see the following:

```
The char is: ├ and its ASCII value is: -61
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: It is not that "`std::string::operator+=()` doesn't know how to convert and append `'a' + 'b'`. The fundamental reason is **operator precedence**. Even if it knows how to convert and append `'a' + 'b'` it will still not do so due to operator precedence.

Comment: This is an ingenious explanation but is sadly not correct.

Comment: @Bathsheba True. I updated the answer. Please cast an upvote if it's good enough.